# The probability of seeing a vertex $v_j$ in less than $K$ steps from another vertex $v_i$

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-walk

I want to calculate the probability of seeing vertex $v_j$ in a random walk in less than $K$ steps from vertex $v_i$ for every pair of vertices. Is there any approach for this problem in polynomial time? Actually I want to calculate the $p(v_j|v_i)$ in a window of width $K$, but my problem is that there might be more than one path from $v_i$ to $v_j$.

Comment: What do you know about the graph? If the graph is finite or regular or something, this sounds a lot easier than in full generality.

Comment: Yeah, we know that graph is finite but not regular, may be with power law degree distribution.

Comment: If the graph is finite, you can solve this with a version of the adjacency matrix. Compute the matrix $A$ that gives you the probability for every vertex after a random walk with $1$ step. To figure out what happens after $K$ steps you only need the $K$th power fo this matrix $A^K$. Note that you only need to compute this matrix once and then can use it for all vertices.

Comment: I thought there might be a better solution with less time complexity that matrix multiplication. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Matrix powers can be computed a lot more efficiently than by just multiplying a matrix by itself over and over again by diagonalizing it first. Whether this actually helps depends on the size of your graph and the range of $K$. If the graph is small and $K$ is big or you want a lot of different values of $K$, this is much faster. If the graph is huge and you only need relatively low values of $K$ just multiplying the matrices might be faster.

Comment: @quarague I should search more about it, so grateful for your help, thanks.